# Update of embedded model does not affect in related collection

Tags: laravel, mongodb, eloquent, lumen, jenssegers-mongodb

**What I get:**

My controller creates one intance of `Message` in the message collection. It contains an embedded instance of `Image`. It also creates a duplicate of the embedded `Image` in the images collection.

After updating the name property of Image the update affects only the embedded instance, but not the related duplicate in the images collection.

**What I want:**

I want a real belonging of the duplicate in the images collection to the embedded Image. I don't want to have update the related Image manually.

Is that possible by using `jenssegers/laravel-mongodb`?

**My model:**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Relations\EmbedsMany;

class Message extends Model
{
    public function images(): EmbedsMany
    {
        return $this->embedsMany(Image::class);
    }
```

**My controller method:**

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $message = Message::create($request->all());

    $imageController = new ImageController();
    $image = $message->images()->associate(
        /* ImageController->create() simply creates an Image object
           without touching the database */
        $imageController->create($request->input('image'))
    );
    $message->save();

    $foo = $message->images()->first();
    $foo->name = 'bar';
    $foo->save();

    return response()->json($message, 201);
}
```